# Long boot time if the computer is not connected to the domain

Tags: boot, windows-domain

All computers in our company are connected to a domain. Now a lot of people reported that their computer need a long time to boot as soon as they are no longer connected to the domain.
I was unable to find a solution for this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do they happen to have network printers/folder shares/network drives configured? Looking for those takes a while.

Comment: There's an example of working out this type of problem here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2012/07/02/3506849.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure the Active Directory DNS server is in the list of DNS servers for each client.

Comment: Can you expand your answer, maybe, and explain how to check that, etc?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to my mind is a 'long' time-out (~30 seconds) on the connection that looks for the domain.
The boot process is a process with many steps, can you be more specific about which steps take longer than normal?

Answer (score 0):

First we must ask why are they taken off the domain. Is this a regular thing with Offline Files?  If not, then why would they not be connected to the domain.  Kind of defeats the purpose of a network, so that is unusual.

You might have the old political joke about "what you are saying is technically accurate,  and absolutely of no use to me in my predicament."

If the network cable was unplugged, it would say so. So you have mis-configured or faulty equipment.  If you're not the IT guy, somebody needs to call him, that's all. Or if you've been the designated fix-it guy, we'll need a lot more specific information.

Still willing to help, but just need all the details you have.

Comment: How does this answer the question?